# ftp error comandos desde consola sendcmd() cambio a modo pasivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

Estoy tratando de realizar un script en Python 3.8 para ftp empleando únicamente comandos ftp vía sendcmd().

```
import ftplib

# connexion al host
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(host='ftp.dlptest.com')
# obtener mensaje de bienvenida
resp = ftp.getwelcome()
print(resp)
# identificar usuario
resp = ftp.sendcmd('USER dlpuser')
print(resp)
# contraseña
resp = ftp.sendcmd('PASS rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu');
print(resp);
# ver directorio
resp = ftp.sendcmd('LIST');
print(resp);
# terminar sesión
resp = ftp.sendcmd('QUIT');
print(resp);
```

Cuando llego a pedir el directorio con sendcmd('LIST') me aparece el error
**ftplib.error_temp: 425 Use PORT or PASV first.**
Hasta antes de eso todo bien, después la nada.

¿Alguna idea de que me falta? Porque asumo que falta algo.

**Atualizo**

Después del apunte de @CandidMoe (ver abajo), y de revisar diversas consultas, como https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536248/telnet-and-passive-ftp, que tuvo la ocurrencia de emplear comandos desde Telnet (yo desde el IDLE), resumo lo encontrado.

Por defecto el servidor arranca la conexión de datos en modo activo desde su puerto 20. Esto puede presentar problemas con los cortafuegos que filtran la conexión del puerto de datos entrante al cliente desde el servidor. La solución pedir al servidor que cambie a modo pasivo (PASV), que es básicamente una solicitud de un puerto del servidor al que conectarse para la transmisión de datos. Cuando el servidor FTP responde, indica qué número de puerto de datos ha abierto para la transferencia de datos.

Con estos palos paso a modificar mi script, y añado antes del comando LIST:

```
# cambio a modo pasivo
resp = ftp.sendcmd('PASV');
print(resp);
if resp.startswith('227'):
    ini = resp.find('(') + 1
    end = resp.find(')')
    host_port = resp[ini:end]
    resp = ftp.sendcmd(f'PORT {host_port}');
    print(resp)
```

Recibo como respuesta al comando PASV:

**227 Entering Passive Mode (35,163,228,146,4,6).**

Ya tengo una dirección IP+Puerto, pero la solución de indicar el puerto al servidor no funciona. Me salta un Traceback con el error:

*ftplib.error_perm: 500 Illegal PORT command.*

En otras páginas indican, sin poner ejemplos, que se necesitaría otra conexión (¿otro script?) que conectara al puerto indicado. Y aquí me pierdo.

Todo comentario es bienvenido y si aporta soluciones mejor.

Comment: FTP tiene dos modos: activo (default) y pasivo. En el modo activo, el servidor establece una conexión de vuelta hacia el cliente. Si hay un firewall entremedio, generalmente habrá problemas. Por eso primero debes cambiar a modo pasivo (comando PASV). En este modo todas las conexiones son desde el cliente al servidor.

Comment: ¿Donde?, porque si lo pongo después de la contraseña y antes de LIST me aparece *227 Entering Passive Mode (35,163,228,146,4,15)* y se queda pensando hasta que me encuentro con el error *ftplib.error_temp: 425 Failed to establish connection.*